# Property 'view' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Tags: ios

i am getting this error when using this code

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor`]

Property 'view' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

This code i placed in the AppDelegate.m file

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are currently typing in the `AppDelegate` class generated by Xcode, `self` refers to an instance of the `AppDelegate` class. Instances of `AppDelegate` by default do not have a `view` property unless you explicitly add one. You could try the app delegate's root view controller's `view` property.

```
self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This assumes that you have assigned a valid instance of a subclass of `UIViewController` to your app delegate's root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

The AppDelegate is designed for allowing the developer to handle application-wide events and state transitions ([More info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AppArchitecture/AppArchitecture.html)).

Based upon the code snippet you posted, the code should exist under a ViewController.

Comment: +1 for advising separation of view logic from the app delegate